# Error : Unable to find keypair GraphLab in ec2

Tags: linux, hadoop, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run run GraphLab in Amazon ec2 cluster.But I am facing some issues regarding the set up. I know its a basic question but I am not able to figure out the issue.
1)When i run the Command 
/gl-ec2 -i ~/.ssh/graphlab.pem -k graphlabkey  -s 1 launch launchtest
for graphlab in ubuntu 
it gives me error

```
Launching instances...
ERROR:boto:400 Bad Request
ERROR:boto:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidKeyPair.NotFound</Code><Message>The key pair 'Prashant-Raghav' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>366d452a-921d-4feb-a9d1-50bf8ccc2f55</RequestID></Response>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gl_ec2.py", line 750, in <module>
    main()
  File "./gl_ec2.py", line 532, in main
    conn, opts, cluster_name)
  File "./gl_ec2.py", line 282, in launch_cluster
    block_device_map = block_map)
  File "/home/hduser/graphlab/scripts/ec2/third_party/boto-2.4.1.zip/boto-2.4.1/boto/ec2/image.py", line 255, in run
  File "/home/hduser/graphlab/scripts/ec2/third_party/boto-2.4.1.zip/boto-2.4.1/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 678, in run_instances
  File "/home/hduser/graphlab/scripts/ec2/third_party/boto-2.4.1.zip/boto-2.4.1/boto/connection.py", line 925, in get_object
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidKeyPair.NotFound</Code><Message>The key pair 'Prashant-Raghav' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>366d452a-921d-4feb-a9d1-50bf8ccc2f55</RequestID></Response>
```

1) I am not able to find the generated .pem file in ssh .
2)I have created a ppk file can I use it for running GraphLab
3)Whats the difference beteern .ppk and .pem
4)Where is keypair stored in Ec2 when i create key pair it stores in windows but is there any way to get in linux so that I can specify the path ..Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you try running this in python to make sure it's there? `print (boto.ec2.get_all_keypairs())`

Comment: Thanks for teh reply I tried ti use the above command but it returns nothing in my case. problem is with the keypair i think,

Answer (score 0):

I have some Improvement on this.. I tried approach of generating the key pair online.Download it in my mahcince and then upload it to amazon s3 .Which you can get in your ubuntu by doing wget.But the problem now is its unable to find the keypair. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the key on your machine, for example in the ec2 folder